# How can I prove the dimension axiom here?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Here is the problem:

> [image]

I want to prove the dimension axiom in (a). My professor gave me the dimension axiom for reduced cohomology as follows:

$$\widetilde{H}^k(S^n ; \mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}, \text{ if } k = n \text{ and } \widetilde{H}^k(S^n ; \mathbb{Z})= 0 \text{ if } k \neq n. $$

And the dimension axiom for homology as follows:

$${H}_n(pt.) = 0, \text{ if } n \geq 1 \text{ and } {H}_n(pt.)=  \mathbb{Z} \text{ if }  n = 0. $$

Could anyone explain to me how I can use those 2 definitions to prove the required, please?

Comment: You need the others too.  Didn't you ask a [similar question](/questions/3780373) a few days ago?

Comment: @user10354138 I do not think that the answer in the question you mentioned answered this question. What do you mean by "You need the others too"?

Comment: @user10354138 also in the other question I was comparing to Rotman and this definition is different from what my professor gave.

Comment: You need the other axioms too, otherwise all you have is the reduced cohomology of $S^n$ and homology of pt, and on other spaces you are free to define them to be whatever.  Clearly that wouldn't give you part (a) at all.  Now what other axioms have you got for $H_n$ and $h^n$?

Comment: @user10354138 for $H_{n}$ I have all axioms of homology theory stated in AT (including the dimension axiom) and for $h^n$ I managed to prove all other axioms of cohomology theory (except surely the dimension axiom that we require to prove)

Comment: @user10354138  I am not excluding all other axioms from my consideration. I am just stating the statement of dimension axioms I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the "dimension axiom" you're citing from your professor is right. Maybe he was talking about the dimension axiom and gave you that result as a consequence of the axiom, but it certainly isn't equivalent to any form of the dimension axiom I've seen. As pointed out in the comments, this axiom isn't restrictive enough to specify the cohomology of spaces built out of suspensions, etc. The one you give for homology is correct, and the natural analog of that axiom for cohomology is $H^n(\text{pt}) = 0$ for $n>0$ and $H^0(\text{pt})$ is your coefficient group.

In your case, your coefficient group will be the underlying group of $R$. Then since $H_n$ is an ordinary homology theory, it satisfies the dimension axiom, so $H_n(\text{pt}) = 0$ for $n>0$. Then $h^n(\text{pt}) = \text{Hom}(0,R) = 0$ for $n>0$. Now, $H_0(\text{pt})\cong R$, so $h^0(\text{pt})\cong\text{Hom}(R,R)\cong R$, as desired.

note: Some of your confusion might be coming from mixing up the definitions of "reduced" theories vs. "ordinary" theories vs. "generalized" theories. These all have slightly different definitions. For example, reduced theories have $\widetilde{H}_n(\text{pt}) = 0$ for $n\geq0$, not just $n>0$. Ordinary theories satisfy all of the usual Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms, and generalized theories don't satisfy the dimension axiom at all, meaning contractible spaces will have nontrivial homology in positive dimension in these theories.

Comment: Thank you so  much for your very keen explanation.